# Sum of Cells in the blank cells in the next column. ( Formula or Appscript)

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sum the cells until I get a blank cell in the column B then add that sum in next column. In the below pic sum of C2:C4 should come in D5,sum of C6:C10 in D11 and so on. Database is so large. So filling formula in every column is not possible. Please find solution to this issue. [image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scan()` and `map()`. Put this formula in cell `D1`:

```
=let( 
  range, C2:C, 
  numRows, arrayformula(xmatch("?*", to_text(range), 2, -1)), 
  data, array_constrain(range, numRows, 1), 
  blank, iferror(ø), 
  subtotals, scan(0, data, lambda(a, c, if(c, a + c, blank))), 
  lastInGroup, map(vstack(subtotals, ""), vstack("", subtotals), lambda(x, y, if(x = "", y, blank))), 
  vstack("Subtotals", lastInGroup) 
)
```

The results look like this:

|  | Name | Amount | Subtotals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Kamla | 10 |  |
|  | Sruthi | 20 |  |
|  | Sarath | 30 |  |
|  |  |  | 60 |
|  | Sasi | 4 |  |
|  | Vinod | 25 |  |
|  | Sarath | 45 |  |
|  | Ravi | 25 |  |
|  | Vipin | 20 |  |
|  |  |  | 119 |
|  | Mini | 30 |  |
|  | Sheethal | 21 |  |
|  |  |  | 51 |
|  | Raju | 25 |  |
|  |  |  | 25 |

See [scan()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569094) and [map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985).

Comment: Use `map(chooserows(vstack(subtotals, ""), sequence(rows(subtotals), 1, 2)), subtotals,`... Please do not ask questions in comments. Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.